# Retrofit - Log4j

Tags: java, log4j, retrofit

I use Retrofit in a java application to access api-rest.

I'm using simple code:

```
RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(uri).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.HEADES_AND_ARGS).setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson)).setClient(httpClient).build();
```

is possible mapping retrofit log to log4j ?

Comment: If you have some question or if you need some explanation please ask :)

Comment: the log generate from retrofit is not wrappin to log4j. how to wrapping to log4j?

Comment: I know you have to create wrapper. Look on my post I will update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use the log from okhttp , the snapshot from the version 2.6.0 which is introduced in the beta2 version of retrofit and going live soon is currently working fine, you can see how to implement it on this guide https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses/
pretty easy to use and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

The `RestAdapter.Builder` has method `setLog(Log)` which get's `RestAdapter.Log` interface as parameter. This interface looks like below:

```
 /** Simple logging abstraction for debug messages. */
  public interface Log {
    /** Log a debug message to the appropriate console. */
    void log(String message);
  }
```

You can set LogLevel as f.e. FULL and create class which wrap log4j and implements `Log` interface and log your logs in `log(String)` method, but you will get all logs as string. There is no possible to check from which level, the log comes.

**EXAMPLE WRAPPER**

```
public class ExampleLog4J implements RestAdapter.Log {
    private static final Logger logger = logger.getLogger(ExampleLogger.class)
    ExampleLog4J(){
    }
    @Override
    public void log(String message) {
        log.info("Retrofit# "+message);
    }
}
```

And in the place where you create RestAdapter use:

```
new RestAdapter.Builder().setLog(new ExampleLog4J()).
```

Comment: public class RetrofitLogger implements Log {

    private static final Logger logger = logger.getLogger(RetrofitLogger.class);
    
    @Override
    public void log(String message) {
 logger.info(message);
 
    }

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setLogLevel(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled() ? retrofit.LogLevel.FULL : retrofit.LogLevel.BASIC)
    .setLog(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled() ? LOGGER::debug : LOGGER::info)
```

`retrofit.LogLevel` is used to specify how much detailed logging you require from Retrofit.

An implementation of `retrofit.RestAdapter.Log` is passed to the `setLog()` of `RestAdapter`. `RestAdapter` delegates all its internal logging to log4j Logger in this case.

Here `LOGGER` is something that you would initialize like below

```
private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOGGER = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
```

`LOGGER::debug` in Java 8 is equivalent to the below anonymous class

```
 new retrofit.RestAdapter.Log() {
      @Override
      public void log(String message) {
          LOGGER.debug(message);
      }
 }
```